# What is the difference between the boundary set and a bounded set?

Tags: real-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Is my notion of boundary and bounded correct?

**Boundary** as I understand it is the set of all points for with we can center a ball B(x,r) with radius r>0 with contains points that are both inside and outside the set.

**Bounded** means there is a certain number C for which is bigger then every point in our set. ie ||x|| < C.

So my question is the following: why does a bounded set need not have a boundary ? *Shouldn't one imply the other?*

Comment: Are you wondering if a bounded set must contain some point of its boundary, or if a nonempty bounded set must have a nonempty boundary?

Comment: And where do your sets live? Euclidean space, any normed linear space, ...?

Comment: In the Euclidean Space, why is it true that a bounded set needs not to have a boundary? I thought that having a set which is bounded also means that that said set must have a boundary?

Comment: It is indeed true that in Euclidean space, a nonempty bounded set must have a nonempty boundary. My answer below explains this. It is not true, however, that any nonempty bounded set must also contain its boundary, for a set contains its boundary if and only if it is closed.

Comment: But I have learned that " A set with a boundary need not be bounded, and a bounded set need not have any boundary points nor contain any of its boundary points if it has any" I don't understand that

Comment: "A set with a boundary point need not be bounded" is true: the set $(0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is unbounded but has the boundary point $0$.

"A bounded set need not have any boundary points" is true: consider the empty set. However, if we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the empty set is the only bounded set which does not have any boundary points. See my answer below.

"...nor contain any of its boundary points if it has any" is true: consider the set $I=(0,1)$. Its boundary points are $0$ and $1$, and neither is in $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundary of a subset $S$ of a topological space is the set of points in the closure which are not in the interior, i.e. $\partial S=\overline{S}\setminus S^\circ$. It is a simple exercise using the definition of boundary point given in your question to prove this.

If $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is nonempty and bounded, then we have both $\overline{S}\neq\emptyset$ and $\overline{S}\neq\mathbb{R}^n$, so that since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected, $\overline{S}$ cannot be both open and closed. If $\partial S=\emptyset$, then this would imply that $\overline{S}=S^\circ$. But this is impossible, since $\overline{S}$ is closed but $S^\circ$ is open.

In fact, any normed linear space is connected (use that path-connected implies connected), so this same argument shows that in any normed linear space, a nonempty bounded set has nonempty boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following counterexample: on the Euclidean plane, the open ball of radius $1$ centered in $(0,0)$ is a *bounded* set, because each point $\mathbf{x}$ in it obeys to the relation $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert \le 1$. However, its boundary is the empty set: because $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert \le 1$, you can assume that
$$
\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert = 1 - \epsilon, \quad \epsilon \in (0,1].
$$
Thus, there are no points which cannot be included in a open ball wholly contained in the set: for $\mathbf{x}$, the open ball centered in it of radius $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is always fully contained in the set.

The *boundary* of a set is made of all the points with the following condition: *every open ball centered in $\mathbf{x}$ both intersect the set and its complement*.

Comment: It is not true that the boundary of that set is empty.

Comment: The boundary of the open ball $B_1(0)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|x\|<1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is NOT empty. It is the set $\{y\in\mathbb{R}:\|y\|=1\}$. If you view $B_1(0)$ as a metric space itself with the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^2$, then sure, $B_1(0)$ has no boundary because its complement in this metric space is empty! But based on the question asker's definition of bounded, it appears that they were asking this question in the setting of normed linear spaces, which $B_1(0)$ considered as a metric space on its own is not.

Comment: Sorry for the typo above. The boundary of $B_1(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2:\|y\|=1\}$, not $\{y\in\mathbb{R}:\|y\|=1\}$.